# Pick event not triggered for select field picker,while importing sencha-touch/base scss

Tags: sencha-touch-2, sencha-touch-2.3

I am having one select field and want to handle select field picker events manually. Following  code for selectfield :

```
{
          xtype: 'selectfield',  
          label: 'Choose one',  
          name:'abcd',  
          usePicker:true,  
          options: [  
              {text: 'First Option',  value: 'first'},  
              {text: 'Second Option', value: 'second'},  
              {text: 'Third Option',  value: 'third'}     

    ],     
    defaultPhonePickerConfig: {  
        hideOnMaskTap: true,  
        listeners: {  
            change: function(ths, val) {
               console.log('change event called');
            },
            pick: function(ths, The, slot) {
              console.log('pick event called');
                PICKER_CONFIG = null;
                if (PICKER_CONFIG != true) {
                    if (The[slot.getName()] != undefined && The[slot.getName()] != null && The[slot.getName()] != "") {
                     //   Ext.getCmp('contractList').setValue(The[slot.getName()]);
                        ths.fireEvent('change', ths, The);
                        ths.hide();
                    }
                }
            },
            cancel: function() {
                console.log('cancel called');
                PICKER_CONFIG = true;
            },
            show:function(){
              console.log('show called');  
            }
        }
    },
```

**pick** is not getting called because i am using base css .

Here is my app.scss

```
@import 'sencha-touch/base';
```

But its working if i am using **sencha-touch default and default/all** css
like:

```
@import 'sencha-touch/default';
@import 'sencha-touch/default/all;
```

but, i **don't want** to use it
Is there  any way to get that **pick** by using **sencha-touch/base css**.

Answer (score 0):

hmm...

Can you tell me from where you get "pick" event ?
And what it supposed to do ?

I'm guessing that its doing the same thing as "change".

And how do you know its because you are using base css ?
from what I read the base css is sencha will be using bare minimum styling for components to work and the rest will be up to user. so there should be no effect on event components behaviour.

Comment: When i will pick and slot in the picker , pick event will called. Change evet will call when will tap on the done button. I tried it. i have two sample project 1 with base css and other with sencha-touch/default/all.

Comment: Even i was thinking there should be no effect on component behavior. but it's happening.

Answer (score 0):

This is what i wrote to set Picker in SelectField:

```
  {
                        xtype: 'selectfield',
                        usePicker: true,
                        displayField: 'text',
                        valueField: 'value',
                        options: [
                            { text: 'Choose Dosage', value: 'default' },
                        ],
                        defaultPhonePickerConfig : {
                            listeners: {
                                change: function(thePicker, newValue, oldValue) {
                                    //check if custom variable has been set to false
                                    if (newValue.slotsNumeric != null && newValue.slotsDecimal != null) {
                                        var total = newValue.slotsNumeric + newValue.slotsDecimal;
                                        // set the select field to show the correct selected value!!
                                        var DecimalPicker = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('selectfield')[0];
                                        DecimalPicker.setOptions({
                                            text: total,
                                            value: total
                                        });
                                    }
                                },
                            },
                            useTitles: true,
                            hideOnMaskTap: true,
                            slots: [
                                {
                                    name  : 'slotsNumeric',
                                    title : 'Numeric',
                                    align: 'center',
                                    data : [
                                        {text: '0', value: 0},
                                        {text: '1', value: 1},
                                        {text: '2', value: 2},
                                        {text: '3', value: 3},
                                        {text: '4', value: 4},
                                        {text: '5', value: 5},
                                        {text: '6', value: 6},
                                        {text: '7', value: 7},
                                        {text: '8', value: 8},
                                        {text: '9', value: 9},
                                    ]
                                }, 
                                {
                                    name  : 'slotsDecimal',
                                    title : 'Decimal',
                                    align: 'center',
                                    data : [
                                        {text: '.0', value: .0},
                                        {text: '.1', value: .1},
                                        {text: '.2', value: .2},
                                        {text: '.3', value: .3},
                                        {text: '.4', value: .4},
                                        {text: '.5', value: .5},
                                        {text: '.6', value: .6},
                                        {text: '.7', value: .7},
                                        {text: '.8', value: .8},
                                        {text: '.9', value: .9},
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        }                   
                    }
```